# Управление уровнем записи микрофона

Tags: cmd, windows-7, vbscript, звукозапись

Здравствуйте
Каким образом/командами можно производить управление громкостью USB-микрофона (либо любого по умолчанию/либо всеми сразу) на Win 7/8.
Желательно через vbs-скрипт, либо батник, чтобы результат можно было навесить на каждый логон юзеров AD.
Либо скрипт, который запретит пользователям управлять окном управления микрофонами

Comment: А в чём закдючается ваш вопрос?

Comment: Есть программа, которая производить захват экрана и звук с подключенного внешнего USB-микрофона. Но в связи с тем что Windows устроен так, что любой пользователь имеет права менять уровень записи звука возникла необходимость реализовать автоматическую регулировку уровня записи звука